# Accessing all Records outside For Loop ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, for-loop, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to get all records as a List from `For Loop`.
Inside that `For Loop` i have a query which returns single record everytime.
Below is my code:

```
 IQueryable<MyClass> receive = null;
     for (int i = 0; i < selected_items.Count(); i++)
      {
        var idx = order_receive_id[selected_items[i]];
        receive = (from ors in db.item where ors.id == 
                   order_receive_idx 
                   select new MyClass()
                   {
                     quantity = ors.receive ?? 0,
                     total = ors.quantity * 250 ?? 0
                   });
      }
```

And then..

```
var com = new MyNewClass();
com.items_list = receive.ToList();
```

But this only shows the last record. I want all the records from above query outside the loop. I couldn't find any help according to my need.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Change `IQueryable<MyClass>` to `List<MyClass>`. Change `receive =` to `receive.AddRange`.

Comment: Because you keep overwriting `receive` in each iteration. But why are you not doing this with one single db call (using a `.Contains()` clause) ?

Comment: If you have an array of ids `[n..m]`, what keeps you from doing a simple `Select foo from x where id in array`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Because i have multiple `ids` and i don't know another way of doing that

Comment: You can use a `.Where(x => .selected_items.Contains(x.id )`

Comment: @mjwills Thank you so much. Your solution worked like a charm. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Keep overwriting the variable receive.

```
recieve.AddRange((from ors in db.item where ors.id == 
                   order_receive_idx 
                   select new MyClass()
                   {
                     quantity = ors.receive ?? 0,
                     total = ors.quantity * 250 ?? 0
                   }));
```

Also if needed you can simplify the query with linq .

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it with `linq`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try Contains in Linq query
like this

```
(from p in GetProducts()
       where prodIDs.Contains(p.ProductID)
       select p).ToArray<Product>();
```